# MacBook Pro slowing down and freezing

Tags: windows-7, macos, macbook

At the beginning I must admit that this is my first MacBook.

I have a problem with my MacBook Pro Mid 2012(i5, 4GB RAM, 500GB HDD). Bought it used but it is not smooth as it should. I installed a fresh OS X Mavericks, and on the second partition Windows 7, on both frozen for a moment and wait cursor appears (spinning pinwheel). When I something select in the top menu I have to wait until it show.

I switched RAM with another laptop, but the problem still the same. I scanned the drive for badsectors and nothing detected.

What could I do it? This freezing is really annoying.

Comment: Run OS X's Disk Utility, select the drive (not a volume; the icon representing the drive itself) and then select `File > Get Info`. Then look at the "Raw Read Error" and "Reallocated Sector Count" counters. If they're nonzero, then you're having drive hardware problems, even if your bad sector scan found nothing.

Comment: Raw Read Error is 0, and Reallocated Sector Count is BC, Should I replace HDD to new?

Comment: Yes. You hard drive is dying, and the problem is likely to snowball. If you don't already have good tested backups, get whatever important data you can off of the drive and replace it. BTW, upgrading to an SSD will greatly increase the speed of your machine.